# PHP Unix time to Human time displaying incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql, unix, time, format

Unix time from MySQL table: `1328422844` posted via `date('U')`

(translates to 2012-02-04 22:20:44)

Displays on HTML page as `Sunday 5th of February 2012 05:20:44 PM` via `date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')`

20 hours ahead of table time... why!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date('U')` assumes GMT timezone. If PHP is not using that timezone or if there is an offset applied, then there's a problem. Just have MySQL use `NOW()` instead.